# Manual "encryption" only outputs 0's to file

Tags: c, file, file-io, bitwise-operators

My assignment (not homework, just a "try if you can do this" thing) is to use bit operations to encrypt and decrypt a .txt file.

This is the program. It successfully opens files for read/write but puts all 0's and spaces into the output.txt file instead of the expected "encrypted" text. I am guessing the issue comes from a fundamental misunderstanding of either data types or putc(). I understand that it outputs an unsigned char, but my professor said that an unsigned char is nothing but an unsigned int -- not sure if this is purely true or if it was a pedagogical simplification. Thanks a lot for any help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NUMARG 3
#define INFILEARG 1
#define OUTFILEARG 2

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    /* Function prototypes */
    unsigned int encryptDecrypt(unsigned int x, unsigned int ed);
    const char *get_filename_ext(const char *filename);

    FILE *finp;
    FILE *foutp;

    //ed for encryption/decryption choice
    unsigned int ed, c;
    const char *ext;

    //Check for errors in argument number and file opening.
    if(argc != NUMARG){
        printf("You have to put the input and output files after the 
                program name.\n");
        return(1);
    }

    if( (finp = fopen(argv[INFILEARG], "r")) == NULL ){
         printf("Couldn't open %s for reading.\n", argv[INFILEARG]);
         return(1);
    }

    if( (foutp = fopen(argv[OUTFILEARG], "w")) == NULL){
        printf("Couldn't open %s for writing.\n", argv[OUTFILEARG]);
        return(1);
    }


    //Get and check file extension.
    ext = get_filename_ext(argv[INFILEARG]);
    if(strcmp(ext, "txt")){
        printf("Input file is not a .txt file.\n");
        return(1);
    }

    ext = get_filename_ext(argv[OUTFILEARG]);
    if(strcmp(ext, "txt")){
        printf("Output file is not a .txt file.\n");
        return(1);
    }

    //Get command to encrypt or decrypt.
    do{
        printf("Enter e to encrypt, d to decrypt: ");
        ed = getchar();
    } while(ed != 'e' && ed != 'd');


    //Send characters to output file.
    while((c = getc(finp)) != EOF ){
         putc(encryptDecrypt(c, ed), foutp);
    }


    // Close files.
    if (fclose(finp) == EOF){
         printf("Error closing input file.\n");
    }

    if (fclose(foutp) == EOF){
        printf("Error closing output file.\n");
    }

    if ( ed == 'e'){
        printf("Encrypted data written.\n");
    } else {
         printf("Data decrypted.\n");
    }

    return 0;
}

const char *get_filename_ext(const char *filename) {
    const char *dot = strrchr(filename, '.');
    if(!dot || dot == filename) return "";
    return dot + 1;
}

unsigned int encryptDecrypt(unsigned int c, unsigned int ed){
    if( ed == 'e' ){
        printf("%d before operated on.\n", c);
        c &= 134;
        printf("%d after &134.\n", c);
        c ^= 6;
        printf("%d after ^6. \n", c);
        c <<= 3; 
        printf("%d after <<3\n", c);
    }
    else {
        c >>= 3;
        c ^= 6;
        c &= 134;       
    }   
    return c;
}
```

Output:

```
ZacBook:bitoperations $ cat input1.txt
Please encrypt this message.
ZacBook:bitoperations $ ./encrypt.o input1.txt output.txt
Enter e to encrypt, d to decrypt: e
80 before operated on.
0 after &134.
6 after ^6. 
48 after <<3
108 before operated on.
4 after &134.
2 after ^6. 
16 after <<3
[...Many more of these debug lines]
2 after &134.
4 after ^6. 
32 after <<3
Encrypted data written.
ZacBook:bitoperations $ cat output.txt
00 0  00000 0  0
```

As you can see, the unsigned int is being operated on successfully. I believe the problem is with putc() but I have tried changing the type of c to char and int and neither have worked.

Comment: Don't prototype functions inside `main`.

Comment: `while((c = getc(finp)) != EOF )` -- `unsigned int c` may not be able to hold `EOF`.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya I think `EOF` will be converted to unsigned and it will work fine.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Indeed you are correct. `EOF` will be converted to `unsigned`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. yes, I agree it will work fine. But it is not advised.

Comment: `& 134` is throwing away 5 out of 8 bits right away, then your `<< 3` is throwing away one of those, so right up front you only have two bits per output character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main problem is that `&=` is a *lossy* transformation: that is you lose data.

Ditto `<<=` and `>>=`, as both cause extreme 1 bits to be lost.

You'll have more luck sticking to XOR; at first at least. That's because `x ^ y ^ y` is `x`.

You can eliminate `putc` &c. by isolating the encryption / decryption processes from the data acquisition stages, and by hardcoding the inputs whilst your getting things working.

Comment: Thank you. I managed to get it to work with only XOR. However, I was under the impression <<= would work as long as the number doesn't exceed (whatever number would take up 31 bits) since the extreme left bit will be 0 regardless.

Comment: No, XOR introduces 1 bits into the pattern.

Comment: Ahh, true. I tried left shifting after XOR, but all of the chars turned into their command versions -- i.e. ^P^L^E^A^S^E^E^N^C^R^Y^P^T ...